# Does anyone know any 'no-interface' game engines?

Tags: architecture, editors, open-source, quake3, quake2

**What I'm looking for:**

I've been searching for a while now for any *no-interface* game engines (What I mean by that Is something like the Source Engine where other than than the level editor It's nothing but pure source code).

**[IMPORTANT] Edit:**

I have deleted the second half of my Initial question as I made a breakthrough with my research realising, Id Tech 3 and 4 seem to be exactly what I was describing, although I still would like to know of any 2D alternatives to Id Tech/Id Tech derived engine.

Comment: "Recommend an engine to use" requests are discussion-oriented questions which involve answers that are either based on opinion, or which are all equally valid. Those kinds of questions are outside the scope of this site. If there's some other question about these engines you have that might be on-topic (as described [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)), please edit accordingly.

Comment: https://orx-project.org/ might work. But a lot of engines might fit the bill if you just ignore their "interface" and instantiate everything with code. I think you can do this with Unity, for example.

Comment: With Unity, you'd still need to go via the editor interface to add assets to your project and configure their import settings, or to configure and generate your executable build — not that this is especially onerous. You could write custom importer code and build scripts to automate most of it if you like, then you'd just have to boot the editor (which you can do in headless mode via the command line) to force the import routines to get invoked on any newly added/changed asset files. I don't *recommend* that style, but it is indeed *possible*, and similar should apply to most engines with GUI.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i didn't know about the no Interface option In Unity, I think what I'm looking for exactly would be classified as a mod engine, open-source source code of a pre existing game released with the intentions of allowing others to create mods or standalone games using It. Should be all good for now, I'll look through the above links and see what there Is.

Comment: Also with my question I meant to word It with the intent of people sharing engines they've heard of for the task without any personal bias or preference In the list, but I see now how it's at high risk of being mistaken as a purely opinion based question.